# Find W/L and Vt of NMOS

Tags: cmos, nmos, vlsi

I'm simply trying to find Vt and W/L for a given practice exam problem shown below:

[image: Practice Exam Problem]

The solution is given as:
[image]

Initially, I was trying to use the equation as shown in line 1 of the solution to develop 2 equations with 2 unknowns and solve for each, but there appears to be a much faster way to arrive at the solution which I'm having trouble understanding. Specifically, I don't understand line 2 of the solution.

What is the logic behind taking the ratio of Id (0.225mA/0.1mA = 2.25)?

The book defines VGT as Vgs-Vt, I don't understand which numbers/logic is used to determine Vgt1/Vgt2 = 1.5. I suspect VGT is not equal to Vgt (lower case), but can't find a formal definition to support my suspicion.

And Finally, how is Vt = 0.6V? The most I can rationalize is that 1.5/2.25 = 0.66667, but doesn't seem right.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.
*This is a practice exam, not hw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply divide the two the equation?

$$\frac{I_{D1}}{I_{D2}} = \frac{\textrm{k}(V_{GS1} - V_T)^2}{\textrm{k}(V_{GS2} - V_T)^2}$$

And the result is

$$\frac{I_{D1}}{I_{D2}} = \frac{(V_{GS1} - V_T)^2}{(V_{GS2} - V_T)^2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{I_{D1}}{I_{D2}}} = \frac{(V_{GS1} - V_T)}{(V_{GS2} - V_T)}$$

The End.

PS. Of course, this is true only if \$V_{DS1} = V_{DS2} = V_{DS}\$ otherwise :
https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/06/adem/engin/e77vlsi/lab4/

Answer (score 1):

The ratio in currents is useful here because current is proportional to the square of overdrive voltage (called \$V_{gt}\$ here and \$V_{ov}\$ in some other courses)<sup>1</sup>. By taking the ratio in currents, you easily get the ratio of overdrive voltages, which is useful in some problems such as this one.

The notation appears to be a result of computing \$V_{gt}\$ at the two provided operating points which were implicitly numbered 1 and 2. \$V_{gt1} = 0.9\,\text{V} - V_t\$ and \$V_{gt1} = 0.8\,\text{V} - V_t\$.

Given \$V_{gt1}/V_{gt2} = 1.5\$, you know that \$\frac{0.9\,\text{V}-V_t}{0.8\,\text{V}-V_t} = 1.5\$. This can be easily seen to be satisfied by \$V_t = 0.6\,\text{V}\$ since 0.3/0.2 = 1.5.

<sup>1</sup> As a simplified model that holds well for strongly-inverted FETs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding to my questions. I'm going to see what I can learn about overdrive voltage right now, but I wanted to say that Vgt1/Vgt2=1.5 isn't given in the question explicitly, but only seems to be shown in the solution. Is there another way you were able to deduce the ratio is equal to 1.5?

Comment: @InterestingGuy The ratio of the two provided currents was 2.25. Since the ratio of the overdrive voltages is the square root of the ratio of currents **assuming everything else is unchanged**, we obtain Vgt1/Vgt2=1.5.